# Flush iptables with ansible

Tags: ansible, iptables, ansible-2.x

How do you use Ansible to flush iptables?  Without locking yourself out of the target system because you denied port 22 in the flush?

The iptables module was released with Ansible 2.0, and the flush parameter was added in Ansible 2.2.  So I am wondering how to use that new option.

I want to do the equivalent of this:

```
$ iptables -F
$ iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
$ iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
$ etc etc
$ iptables-save
```

I have tried doing a:

```
- name: Reset iptables to blank slate
  command: "{{item}}"
  with_items:
    - 'iptables -F'
    - 'iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT'
    - 'iptables-save'
```

Which locked me out of SSH.

I'm assuming that using the following will have the same effect:

```
-iptables: flush
 become: yes
```

Answer (score 1):

Write a shell script that will execute all commands you need and fire it in [async](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_async.html) mode.

Also you can change default policy to `ACCEPT` before flushing and revert it afterwards.
There is [iptables_raw](https://github.com/Nordeus/ansible_iptables_raw) custom module that can do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

The syntactically proper task in your play would be:

```
- iptables:
    flush: yes
```

But yes, that will mostly work. This is equivalent to running `iptables --flush` and `iptables --save` on the system. This will NOT, however, forward 22 again. To do so you must add an additional task. For example with the `firewalld` module:

```
- firewalld:
    port: "22
    state: enabled
    permanent: yes
```